# Monitor has Speaker Out Port, can I plug Headphones into it?

Tags: speakers, headphones

Is it possible for a speaker output port on a Dell U3417W Monitor, which has no headphone output port, operate headphones?

Comment: You may want to check the specs on this hardware to see if the specs from the manufacturer website may answer this question for you if you have not done that already. If it's HDMI on the monitor, then I know HDMI carries sound for example.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

The U3417W monitor **does** have a headphone output (*although if the monitor is on your desk, you'll need to be a skilled yoga student to reach it*)

To get sound out of it though, you'll need to disable speakers in the monitor's menu

[image]